# Yii2 PHP 7.1.3 - Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen()

Tags: php, yii

I updated php from 7.0 to 7.1, and now I am getting this error:

```
Call to undefined function yii\helpers\mb_strlen()
```

I run this command (and restarted the server):

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

Got this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.1-mbstring is already the newest version (7.1.3+-3+deb.sury.org~xenial+1).
The following package was automatically installed and is no longer required:
  rlwrap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove it.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 36 not upgraded.
```

Tried everything, but the error is still here.

Screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Check with phpinfo in mbstring extension is enabled.

Comment: It is enabled. I think I am missing something. (gonna edit the question to upoload screen shot)

Comment: Does this error come from the console code?

Comment: The error in the console is a bit different (yii related issues..)

Comment: @Sasha so this error comes from the web and not console?

Comment: Yep. I am deleting php and reinstalling it. Gonna see what is will happen.